# How to host 2 nodejs servers running on different ports(3000 and 5000) using nginx in one virtual machine(azure)

Tags: azure, nginx, virtual-machine, virtualhost, nginx-config

Is it possible to access the 2 nodejs servers like, `public_ip:3000` and `public_ip:5000`?
I have an `index.js` and `app.js` file in `/var/www/html` folder. `index.js` runs on port `3000` and `app.js` runs on port `5000`. I am able to access only the server running on port 3000. If I try to access the other server by `public_ip:5000` I am getting a 502 Error.

This is `/etc/nginx/site-available/default` file config.

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    
    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
         proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    
    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
         proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check that the Node.js server running on port 5000 is running and listening on the correct port using `sudo netstat -tlnp | grep 5000` If the server is not running start running node `/var/www/html/app.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a mistake wait let me correct and put the updated code try it once and let me know.

```html
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location /app1/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /app2/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

I added path prefixes (/app1/ and /app2/) to the location blocks. http://public_ip/app1/ for the Node.js server running on port 3000 and http://public_ip/app2/ for the one on port 5000.
Also added a trailing slash to the proxy_pass URLs.

```html
sudo service nginx restart
```

don't forget to restart NGINX for the changes to take effect.